# Where is the Eclipse Plugin update error log?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, logging

when I try to update one Eclipse plugin, it show the following error, but I did not find anything under Eclipse folder, where is the log path?

```
an error has occurred, see the error log for details
```

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log is located at current workspace: {workspace_path}/.metadata/.log - also you can view this log in view "Error Log": Window > Show View > Other > Find here "Error Log"