# Eclipse cannot open android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse was working perfectly with my android project and then I received a popup stating that my system is low on disk space on drive C:. I deleted some files from C drive (approx 2 GB) and then restarted my system.

On restarting, eclipse refused to open my android project. I can see the name of my project with a folder icon in Package view window, but i cannot open it either by double clicking it or by selecting the option 'Open Project' by right clicking it. No error messages are displayed.

The contents of the project are intact on the physical device.

I had no joy by trying to import this project into eclipse. It turned down the request by saying that this project already exists.

Comment: What does the error log contain? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884806/where-is-the-eclipse-plugin-update-error-log/7884963#7884963)

Comment: I tried to delete the above mentioned project and import it again. This time I received the following error message: Failed to read the project description file (.project) for 'MyProject'. The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information. The project will not function property until the description file is restored to a valid state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You may delete the project from eclipse by right clicking the project folder icon. (Do not check the `Delete project contents from disc` checkbox)
- You may delete the `.project` and `.classpath` files from the physical location
- Create a new Android project, chose the `Create project from existing source` option

Comment: follow same steps .. no errors .. but the project doesn't appear AT ALL in the workspace folder !! (even though I checked the box: copy projects into workspace) .. what should I do ?

Comment: This worked for me, even after about 3 years. Thank you!