# Eclipse Failure in importing existing Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Hell . . . Failed to read the project description file (.project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345276/eclipse-hell-failed-to-read-the-project-description-file-project)

I tried to import an existing application using the import feature, and instead i got the error pop up below. I would appreciate any help please.

[image]

Content of the .Project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>NFCFakeProjects</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of the original project, then try to replace the .project file located inside the root directory of your Andriod project. Alternatively, try to open .project file and check for any invalid content.

Comment: This is the backup doing this. Hence the reason why I believe this is an issue in my eclipse settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with .project file to overcome this problem create **`new android project`** and then copy your existing **`src`** and **`res`** folder and put it inside newly created `project` which should give back your project.

Comment: I have tried that solution. But somehow I keep ending back here. I downloaded this particular project from the samples that come with Android, yet I get this particular error in this case

Comment: @Kobojunkie Create a new workspace then try importing your project