# Eclipse won't open after Installing Windows Builder

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse's Windows Builder through this [link](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201506241200-1/4.4/) which is from Eclipse org itself. After the installation was complete, my Eclipse just won't open anymore. There's no errors log, it will appear the loading screen and close. as you can see [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ra6fHT5BOos).

How can I fix this problem? Thanks

EDIT: The last session was 2015-07-04 at 11:45. This was when I tried to download and install Windows Builder. It is filled with a bunch of "(something) will be ignored because a newer version is already installed" and at the very bottom this is the last thing that it shows

!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2015-07-04 11:54:38.763
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.actf.visualization.feature.group [1.2.0.R201406111357] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2015-07-04 12:14:26.294
!MESSAGE Connection to http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/releases/luna/201409261001/plugins/org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.workspace.ui.source_0.8.1.201409171422.jar failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Sorry if it's disorganized

Comment: There should be an error log in your workspace's [`.metadata/.log` file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884963/800579). Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: This link is helpful  [link](http://superuser.com/questions/649955/windows-builder-eclipse-error-1)

Comment: I found it, but I don't understand what I need to do...

Comment: Does the error log contain any stack traces or error messages? If so, add them to your question.

Comment: @cyfur01 I just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to try to repeat the process with a clean installation of Eclipse.

One thing you can try changing is where it downloads the WindowBuilder plugin from (got that idea from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/236078/)). Go to the [WindowBuilder website](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) and copy the "Release Version" "Update Site" link for your version of Eclipse. Paste that as the "source" in the "Install New Software" window.

The link for Eclipse Luna should be:

> http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201506241200-1/4.4/